# Using VPN service during prelogin mode

Tags: big-sur, filevault, vpn

I know that it's possible to run openVPN as a daemon service so it can start operate in prelogin mode ... it's useful so I can have access to the LDAP server that verify user credentials in loginwindow stage.

However, what about when fileVault is set.

is there any option to create a tunnel before user has provided fileVault credentials ?

Comment: Are we talking about macOS 11?

Comment: @Gilby, yes, starting from macOS 11 the network is up during fileVault stage, in order to support smartcard based authentication. But if my LDAP can only be accessible through tunnel, so I should i start my VPN when it's installed in the encrypted partition.

Comment: I will get rapidly out of my depth with smart card auth.  But I can't see how you can start a VPN before logon, because all its details are in the FileVault encrypted volume which is only available after logon. Hope someone can show me wrong.

Comment: But there should be a volume which is readable during the fileVault stage (otherwise we couldn't run the loginwindow and the network) do you know which volume is this, and if it can be writable ?

Comment: The system volume is split into two. The read-only sealed system volume which contains macOS code and presents the login screen. The read-write volume is encrypted by FileVault and locked until successful login.